# Pandas посчитать сумму часов за месяц

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Есть задача, в которой суть заключается в выводе суммы часов за месяц, данные берутся из датафрейма, который берется из дб, данные в дб поступают из телеграмм бота:

| Name | date_reg | time_reg | date_start_job | time_start_job | time_end_job |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| @test1 | 21-05-2021 | 11:18 | 22-05-2021 | 10:00 | 19:07 |
| @test2 | 21-05-2021 | 12:13 | 22-05-2021 | 9:58 | 20:04 |

Пробовал сравнивать дату(год и месяц) в столбце с датой и дату(год и месяц) на текущий момент, с помощью datetime, но данный способ не универсален:

```
month = dt.datetime.today()
date = month.strftime("%Y-%m")
tetsd = df['date_start_job'] == date
```

Сумму получаю по всем месяцам, но по отдельным месяцам вычленить ее не получается:

```
datedf = df.groupby(['name', 'date_start_job']).first()
kek = datedf.groupby('name').sum()
```

На выходе должен получиться фрейм с указанием "name", месяцем и суммой часов за этот месяц:

| name | month | summ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| @test1 | 05 | 09:07 |
| @test2 | 05 | 10:46 |

В моем же случае сейчас считается вся сумма часов без оглядки на месяц.

Буду признателен за помощь, или в каком направлении копать.

Comment: приведите пример исходного датафрейма, для воспроизведения.

Comment: @strawdog Подскажите пожалуйста, Вам нужен пример в каком виде?

Comment: Кирилл, в тестовом (csv) виде, можно ссылкой на файлообменник, чтобы было с чем работать.

Comment: @strawdog Теперь понял! Прошу: 
https://disk.yandex.ru/d/L4jAU55hzHcQHA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Моя попытка решения вашей задачи

Исходные данные:

```
Name    date_reg    time_reg    date_start_job  time_start_job  time_end_job
@test1  21-05-2021  11:18   21-05-2021  10:00   19:07
@test2  21-05-2021  12:13   21-05-2021  9:58    20:00
@test1  21-05-2021  12:13   21-05-2021  9:24    20:04
@test2  21-05-2021  12:13   22-05-2021  9:58    19:04
@test1  21-05-2021  12:13   21-04-2021  9:34    20:04
@test2  21-05-2021  12:13   21-02-2021  9:58    20:10
@test1  21-05-2021  12:13   21-04-2021  9:58    20:04
@test2  21-05-2021  12:13   21-02-2021  9:15    20:04
@test1  21-05-2021  12:13   21-03-2021  9:58    21:00
@test2  21-05-2021  12:13   21-02-2021  5:16    20:04
```

Типы данных:

```
Name              object
date_reg          object
time_reg          object
date_start_job    object
time_start_job    object
time_end_job      object
dtype: objectэ
```

Решение:

```
(df
 # Конвертируем строки в дату и время
 .assign(time_start_job=pd.to_datetime(df.time_start_job))
 .assign(time_end_job=pd.to_datetime(df.time_end_job))
 
 # Считаем разницу между начальным и конечным временем
 .assign(time_spent=lambda x: (x.time_end_job - x.time_start_job))

 # Группируем датафрейм по имени и году-месяцу
 .groupby(['Name', pd.to_datetime(df.date_start_job).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')])
 
 # Считаем сумму потраченного времени для каждой группы
 ['time_spent'].sum()

 # Можно получить сумму в секундах, чтобы потом пересчитать как хочется 
 #['time_spent'].sum().dt.total_seconds()
 
 .reset_index(name='time_spent_sum')
)
```

Результат:

```
     Name date_start_job time_spent_sum
0  @test1        2021-03 0 days 11:02:00
1  @test1        2021-04 0 days 20:36:00
2  @test1        2021-05 0 days 19:47:00
3  @test2        2021-02 1 days 11:49:00
4  @test2        2021-05 0 days 19:08:00
```

Для ваших данных результат такой:

```
                  name date_start_job  time_spent_sum
0  AndryshchenkoSergey        2021-05 1 days 21:57:00
1  AndryshchenkoSergey        2021-06 0 days 17:21:00
2               wt4565        2021-05 0 days 02:18:00
3              z6_1_02        2021-05 0 days 08:03:00
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, Вы просто спасли мои мозги от взрыва, я много раз натыкался на такой способ, но не мог осознать его. Как же я был слеп... Спасибо!

Comment: Андрей, на Вашей практике бывало такое, что данный алгоритм вместо месяцев группирует по дням? Если нет, то что то очень странное происходит т.к. сейчас он группирует по дням и году.

Comment: Поправочка, решение работает, залагал тип записи в бд `'%d-%m-Y'`, такой тип записи не корректен для дальнейших действий в Pd. Верная запись в бд `'%Y-%m-%d'`.

Comment: @КириллВолков я не понял, проблема решена?

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего создать ещё одну колонку, в которой будет записано время работы за сессию. Затем просто применить к столбцу с датой (в пандасовском формате, конечно) метод resamlpe. Что-то вроде этого должно работать:

```
df['summ'] = df[time_end_job] - df[time_start_job]
print(df.query('name == "test1"').resample('1M', on='date_start_job'))
```

Тогда в последней колонке будет суммарное время за месяц.